# My back tire rubbing frame

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, rear-wheel

My back tire is rubbing on the frame and is having a great impact on the speed of my cycle.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add pics of the wheel axle in the rear dropouts/slots from both sides?

Comment: What is the width of the tire. It looks too large for the frame. Some budget frames will be limited to circa 2.0

Comment: In addition to @ArgentiApparatus's comment, can you clarify if the tire rubs on both sides of the frame or only on one (from the third picture it looks like it only rubs on the left). Does that change as the wheel rotates or is it constantly rubbing on the left?

Answer (score 7):

Your wheel axle is not aligned in the dropouts properly, causing the rim of the wheel to deviate to one side and contact the frame.

I'm guessing you have horizontal or diagonal slotted dropouts and the drive side of the hub has been pulled forward by the force of the chain. You need to re-align the wheel.

This video from Park Tool is about single speed bikes but the wheel alignment art applies to derailleur equipped bikes as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is not the wheel being improperly installed like @Argenti Apparatus suggested in his answer, you might have a wheel that's not dished properly. Fixing this involves wheel truing with a truing stand, a nipple wrench, and a wheel dish gauge.

Comment: I'd like to add that if the wheel rubs against the frame on only part of the rotation, the wheel is severely out of true (which I have only seen with a broken spoke).